# Getting a missing template error in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I am new to Ruby and am getting the below error when clicking a link in my app that should render a form used to create a user profile. I really appreciate any help with this.

> Missing template profiles/new, application/new with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee]}. Searched in: * "/home/ubuntu/workspace/app/views" * "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/devise-3.4.1/app/views"

**models/profile.rb**

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

**controllers/profiles_controller.rb**

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    # form where a user can fill out their own profile.
    @user = User.find( params[:user_id] )
    @profile = @user.build_profile
  end
end
```

**app/views/profiles/new.html.erb**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <h1 class="text-center">Create Your Profile</h1>
    <p class="text-center">Be a part of the Dev Match community and fill out        your profile!</p>
<div class="well">
  <%= form_for @profile, url: user_profile_path do |f| %>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :first_name %>
      <%= f.text_field :first_name, class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :last_name %>
      <%= f.text_field :last_name, class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :job_title %>
      <%= f.select :job_title, ['Developer', 'Entrepreneur', 'Investor'], {}, class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :phone_number %>
      <%= f.text_field :phone_number, class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :contact_email %>
      <%= f.text_field :contact_email, class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :description %>
      <%= f.text_area :description, class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.submit "Update Profile", class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

**config/locales/routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: 'users/registrations' }
   resources :users do
    resource :profile
   end
   resources :contacts
  get '/about' => 'pages#about'
  root 'pages#home'
end
```

Comment: Looks like the error is coming from devise? If so, you need to follow the readme for devise gem on how to set up devise properly.

Comment: Show your routes, please

Comment: Sorry. Routes added. @trueinViso: It is because of devise?

Comment: Yes, for example the controller needs to inherit from devise, you need views in the devise folder.  More info here: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki

Comment: I tried re-installing but it did not work. And the other forms I have created in the app using Devise have worked fine by the way. Does anyone else have some advice?

Comment: If you have a mounted resource (not simply namespaced), you should probably also have `views/users/profiles/...`

Comment: @Ruby Racer: Sorry but I am a very junior dev. What is a "mounted resource" and why would the absence of a views/users/profiles folder cause this error? Also, I am following a tutorial and my folder/file directory strucure is the same as the instructor and his page is rendering fine. Makes no sense. I must be missing something!!!

Comment: Does anyone know the answer to this issue?

Comment: I am using the term mounted because I see your controllers is under `app/controllers/users` folder. Is it foul to assume that your views should follow the same logic?

Comment: No, not at all! Just trying to better understand how that can be connected to the issue since I am VERY junior. My understanding is that a user request comes in, server receives it, hands it off to the Web Server, goes to the Rails app, goes to the routes file, routes file hands it off to the specific controller requested, controller accesses the correct model file, model hands data back to controller, and then controller accesses appropriate view to render client-side. If this is correct then app/views/profiles/new.html.erb file listed above should be visible and accessible, correct?

Comment: I tried adding a users folder to views to keep consistent with the controller folder pattern but I get the same error. Anyone else have an idea?

Answer (score 1):

First, no need to include your controller inside a folder

**controllers/users/profiles_controller.rb**

unless you are using namespace

Whenever you do that, you should namespace your routes like this

```
namespace :users do
  resources :profiles
end
```

and your controller will be like this

```
class Users::ProfilesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    # form where a user can fill out their own profile.
    @user = User.find( params[:user_id] )
    @profile = @user.build_profile
  end
end
```

That's how to use a namespace.

Now on your problem, try first to moved the profiles_controller.rb to upto controller folder like this

**controllers/profiles_controller.rb**

Answer (score 1):

I probably deserve a beating for this but the reason for the error was that my view/profiles folder was incorrectly typed as "profliles"! I corrected it and the page is rendering fine now. Thank you for all your help on this. I am going to go put my head in the sand now....

Answer (score 0):

Move profiles/new.html.erb under the users folder. Make it app/views/users/profiles/new.html.erb

Or

move controller out of users namespace